# Expression evaluation in assignment

Tags: c++

I was just surprised to see that on GCC (4.3.2) the left hand side of an assignment expression might be evaluated before the right hand side:

```
int x,y;

int& getX()
{
  std::cout << "getX\n";
  return x;
}

int& getY()
{
  std::cout << "getY\n";
  return y;
}

void test()
{
  x = 3; y= 4;
  getX() = getY();
}
```

Calling test() outputs

```
getX
getY
```

Whereas on MSVC, the opposite order is used. Is there any definition by the standard about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

In essence, the Standard defines that it is unspecified, and only guarantees that the arguments will be ready when the function is called.

*EDIT: even worse, the expressions evaluation could be interleaved. See example.*

Basically you should just remember that whenever you have a function, and `a = b` is a function call: `operator=(a , b)`, then the order in which the arguments of the functions are evaluated is unspecified.

GCC usually goes right to left, but the optimizer could decide that sometimes left to right is faster for example. It could even change at runtime, though for practical reasons I have never seen such an implementation.

**EDIT:**

Since the Standard does not promise a particular ordering or even atomic execution, the following statement:

```
test(foo() + bar(), fud());
```

Can result in the 4 following call sequences:

- foo, bar, fud
- bar, foo, fud
- fud, foo, bar
- fud, bar, foo

which are more or less "expected" when you understand the "unspecified" term and its consequences... but it can also lead to the 2 following sequences:

- foo, fud, bar
- bar, fud, foo

which are much more surprising. This is interleaving.

I have left out the `+` operation here, which can only be executed once `foo` and `bar` have been computed, but may be executed before or after `fud`.

If the functions are pure, or have completely disjoint operation sets, it should not matter. Sometimes there are some suprising side effects though, and it may even lead to memory leaks...

Comment: I don't think an in-depth explanation has anything to do with sequence points.

Comment: I do :) For example: `i = ++i + 1;` being undefined is a consequence of sequence points.

Comment: I don't see any relation between this example (in your comment) and the topic. The *order* of evaluation of operands in an expression beig unspecified is one thing, and other expression invoking undefined behavior is another thing.

Comment: @Nawaz: Ah, I understand what you are getting at. Indeed sequence points do not influence the order of evaluation, they *only* influence whether or not the expression has a defined behavior. I have removed that part.

Answer (score 2):

The standard leaves the order of evaluation unspecified, meaning that an implementation may pick whichever order it wants.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator `=` famously does not introduce a sequence point in C++98/03, or in C++11 the expressions on either side are unsequenced with respect to one another.

Answer (score 2):

The order of operands evaluation of operator= is unspecified according to the spec:

> Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is unspecified`